# Xamarin.Forms: Set BackgroundImage from embedded image

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Froms, is it possible to set an embedded image as my BackgroundImage?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images

Comment: I have, and it's not possible to set an embedded image as Content BackgroundImage with this method :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do that directly.

You can, however, create a new [custom renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UsingCustomRenderers/) that inherits PageRenderer, add a new bindable property to a custom Page, such as BackgroundImageFromFile and handle that in the renderer